# microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a windows application with Ms access database(.mdb) and Visual Studio 2012,when first time i run the application error occurred says :

`microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 is not registered in the local machine`

After seeing all posts i resolved this error by make a change from AnyCpu to X86,then its working fine in Visual studio runtime.....

But..Now i created a setup and when i run the setup then same error occurred here on the developer PC.

PC configuration :

Windows 8,VS2012,64bit

Please let me know what to do here.

Comment: @fvu How can there be both versions? If I remember correctly, there *is* no 64-bit version of Jet.

Comment: @CodyGray bad phrasing, sorry for that - let's just say it is a mess once you start mixing 32 and 64.  Still searching for my notes ... :)

Comment: @CodyGray Jet functionality is provided by ACE nowadays, see my reply, and ACE comes in 32 and 64 bits flavors.

Comment: The standard oops here is to make the Platform target change for your Debug configuration but not for the Release configuration.

Comment: how to do this Sir Hans please can you tell me??

Comment: @user1594990 How u fix this error?This error still occur on 2018. :(

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this issue open the project in Visual Studio then:

1. From the solution explorer right-click your project then click Properties
2. Click the Build tab
3. Change Platform target from: Any CPU to x86
4. Re-build your solution

5.Check if traget platform of the setup is x86

Comment: I have tried this and it resolved the issue in Visual studio now the same error comes when i run the setup in 64 bit of PC.Please tel me how to run it on 64 bit as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what runtime you are using, but probably the [Access Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255), which exists in 32 and 64 bits incarnations.  As far as I know you cannot have both installed simultaneously, and the 64 bits one will not serve 32 bits apps and vice versa.

My solution has been to impose the 32 bits runtime and edit the UDL file not by clicking it, but by editing it with eg

```
C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile C:\test.udl
```

as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaitanya_medikonduri/archive/2008/04/09/how-to-run-32-bit-udl-file-on-a-64-bit-operating-system.aspx)

You may also find [this information](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/windows-2008-the-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/) helpful, I admit that my workaround is maybe a bit heavyhanded, but it was the easiest way to avoid the issue...

Comment: Hi,Thx to reply, i installed Access Red.32 bit in my pc but stil error is same and when i tried to install the 64 bit,it says you can not install the 64bit with your Ms office 32 bit.

Comment: As you compiled for x86 your app should be 32 bits, and you should not install the 64 bits version.  If your run that command I suggested on some random UDL file, do you see the MS Jet 4.0 provider in the OLE DB provider list?

Comment: But my PC is 64 bit.. and when i run the setup error occurs please let me know what to do?? :(

Comment: As I said, I went the fully 32 bits road (app and ACE) on both 32 and 64 bits machines, as it's the only reliable solution I managed to get working.  How that's done is explained in my answer.  Look in the right column of this page, there are other questions related to this issue, maybe the problem you are experiencing is different and maybe these other questions have answers with useful info.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver is incompatible with 64 bit Windows, that is why you are getting the error. If you have other applications using that connection string, they are more than likely set up to run in Windows 32 bit mode.

MS has released a driver that'll run in both 32 and 64 bit modes, you can find it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255